# FXAA Parameter Confusion

Tags: fragment-shader, antialiasing

I have a question about the popular FXAA shaders that are out there written using HLSL or GLSL, and they all mainly feature these three parameters:

```
#define FXAA_REDUCE_MIN (1.0 / 128.0)  //0.0078125
#define FXAA_REDUCE_MUL (1.0 / 8.0)  //0.125
#define FXAA_SPAN_MAX 8.0
```

What is the function of each parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user *kingeric1992* who answered in [this other forum](http://reshade.me/forum/shader-discussion/1641-fxaa-parameter-confusion):

> the inquired algorithm performs 1D sampling on direction perpendicular to luminance gradient with varying range with following behavior:
>
> reduce sample range by nearby sum with scale factor defined by
>
> FXAA_REDUCE_MUL: reduce scale multiplier
>
> and
>
> FXAA_REDUCE_MIN : minimum reduce scale
>
> after that, FXAA_SPAN_MAX will force clamp the sample range.
>
> as the out come, the sampling vector (A, B ) will be characterize as (A', B') with min(A', B') < 1, and if |A - B| < scale factor, max(A', B') will also be less then 1, that == no blurring.